# Is there any possibility to log some message only once?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I need to log some warn message only once WITHOUT introducing boolean flag, like `hasBeenLogged = true` and etc.

Suppose, I have following code snippet (rough example):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    log.warn("some message");
}
```

I want to log this warn message only one time, not 35 times..

Is there any possibility (out of box) in `slf4j` or `log4j` to make it possible?

Thanks to all.

Comment: How are you logging today? Any logging framework you are using? Where have you used your flag? Any custom code?

Answer (score 1):

In `log4j 2` there is `RegexFilter`, but this is not exactly what you need, since it only allows to filter out all occurrences of a message.

If you consider alternatives, `Logback` features `DuplicateMessageFilter`. This filter does exactly what you need. Please see the documentation [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter). Since you are using `slf4j`, there should be no problems to switch an implementation behind the facade from `log4j` to `Logback`. You can find a lot of tutorials on that in Google.